# Change httpd.conf of specific user

Tags: centos, httpd.conf

I want to change the httpd.conf file of a specific user on our server. I've found the main httpd.conf file, but I can't find the httpd.conf file for a specific user.

I'm running CentOs 6.4

Answer (score 0):

Found it: /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/USER/httpd.conf